# How to add a custom intellisense to VSCode baseed on the output of a shell command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions, docbook

i have a shell script that extracts defined entities for a given DocBok XML document. Its output looks similar to:

```
&productname;
&productnameshort;
&grub;
```

and so on. I'd like to code an intellisense inside my extension that would be populated by pressing `&` and then filtered by subsequently pressed letter. By pressing `&pr` the intellisense list would populate the first 2 lines of the above example. Any idea?

Comment: the extension [Complete from File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.complete-from-file) has this functionality